# ADODB.Recordset: referencing columns with troublesome names- vb6 solution fails in vb .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, adodb, recordset

I have some old vb6 code that I'm moving to .NET. It uses ADODB recordsets, and some of the column names are troublesome: starting with digits or containing spaces. VB6 worked by enclosing them in brackets, but VB .NET throws a compile error.

Reference to typical column name:

```
rsVals!Break1Yr4
```

References to troublesome column names:

```
rsVals![1_yr]

rsVals![Gross 1 Year]
```

Sample code:

```
Dim rsVals As New ADODB.Recordset
rsVals.Open("Mf_BarChart", conn)
Dim Net1Yr, Gross1Yr
Net1Yr = rsVals![1_Yr]
Gross1Yr = rsVals![Gross 1 Year]
```

That compiles fine on VB6. However, in .NET the reference to [1_Yr] gives 'identifier expected' and the reference to [Gross 1 Year] gives 'Bracketed Identifier is missing closing ']'"
I have not been able to come up with a syntax it will accept. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Any reason you choose to linger in the last century rather than use ADO.NET?

Comment: Not that I am fond of the last Century but this is a huge pile of legacy crap, won't be extended. I'm trying to get the most painless port possible. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `!` notation, try the Fields property on the recordset:

```
Net1Yr = rsVals.Fields("1_Yr")
Gross1Yr = rsVals.Fields("Gross 1 Year")
```

You won't need to use the brackets on the column name for the Fields property - though if you include that column on the column list of your select statements the brackets are (still) needed there.

Comment: Thanks! I happened to stumble over that shortly after asking the question (always works that way, huh?). Too bad for me, the old form of reference (recordset!column) returns a type 'field' in .NET, which won't play well with anything. Seems like VB6 must have been casting it transparently somehow. So I guess I will have to change all of references to use .value(), not just the bracketed ones.